# How to unwrap bulk plsql packages?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, cmd, unwrap

I have the below code in a bat file to wrap all the packages present in a folder where the bat file was executed.

```
@echo off
for /R %%f in (*.pkb) do (
                wrap iname="%%~dpnxf" oname="%%~dpnf.plb"
                DEL %%~dpnxf
)
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to unwrap all the packages present in that folder?

Comment: wrap is an one-way encryption process for the files. there is no un-wrap function

Comment: Thanks @Tejash. Since there is no unwrap function is there any other way to unwrap bulk package files ?

Comment: Use this page: https://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/

Comment: Thanks, @WernfriedDomscheit. This web page will help us to unwrap a single package file. But I have more than 100 packages to unwrap. So is there any way to unwrap bulk packages or a script/code which does that?

Comment: The webpage is very simple, I think it should be not big deal to script the HTML calls.

Comment: What do you think about the answer? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

There are some tools that could help you.

- Python: [unwrap.py](https://github.com/DarkAngelStrike/UnwrapperPLSQL/blob/master/unwrap.py)
- Java: [unwrapper-for-sql-developer](https://www.salvis.com/blog/plsql-unwrapper-for-sql-developer/)

Probably, the Python script is easier to use from terminal.

Java solution is in fact a plugin presented as a *.jar, but it is quite simple to extract the essential part from it.

All you need for this task is 5 *.class files in the **com.trivadis.unwrapper.util** package.
Maybe decompiling them could make the picture clear.

To unwrap one package just call

```
String wrappedCode = ???.getPackageCode();
String sourceCode = Unwrapper.unwrap(wrappedCode);
```

The basic algorithm is as follows:

```
package com.trivadis.unwrapper.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;

public class Unwrapper {
  private static int[] charmap = new int[]{61, 101, 133, 179, 24, 219, 226, 135, 241, 82, 171, 99, 75, 181, 160, 95, 125, 104, 123, 155, 36, 194, 40, 103, 138, 222, 164, 38, 30, 3, 235, 23, 111, 52, 62, 122, 63, 210, 169, 106, 15, 233, 53, 86, 31, 177, 77, 16, 120, 217, 117, 246, 188, 65, 4, 129, 97, 6, 249, 173, 214, 213, 41, 126, 134, 158, 121, 229, 5, 186, 132, 204, 110, 39, 142, 176, 93, 168, 243, 159, 208, 162, 113, 184, 88, 221, 44, 56, 153, 76, 72, 7, 85, 228, 83, 140, 70, 182, 45, 165, 175, 50, 34, 64, 220, 80, 195, 161, 37, 139, 156, 22, 96, 92, 207, 253, 12, 152, 28, 212, 55, 109, 60, 58, 48, 232, 108, 49, 71, 245, 51, 218, 67, 200, 227, 94, 25, 148, 236, 230, 163, 149, 20, 224, 157, 100, 250, 89, 21, 197, 47, 202, 187, 11, 223, 242, 151, 191, 10, 118, 180, 73, 68, 90, 29, 240, 0, 150, 33, 128, 127, 26, 130, 57, 79, 193, 167, 215, 13, 209, 216, 255, 19, 147, 112, 238, 91, 239, 190, 9, 185, 119, 114, 231, 178, 84, 183, 42, 199, 115, 144, 102, 32, 14, 81, 237, 248, 124, 143, 46, 244, 18, 198, 43, 131, 205, 172, 203, 59, 196, 78, 192, 105, 54, 98, 2, 174, 136, 252, 170, 66, 8, 166, 69, 87, 211, 154, 189, 225, 35, 141, 146, 74, 17, 137, 116, 107, 145, 251, 254, 201, 1, 234, 27, 247, 206};

  public Unwrapper() {
  }

  public static String unwrap(String wrapped) throws DataFormatException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String wrappedUnix = wrapped.replace("\r\n", "\n");
    Pattern lengthPattern = Pattern.compile("([\n][0-9a-f]+[ ])([0-9a-f]+[\n])");
    Matcher m = lengthPattern.matcher(wrappedUnix);
    if (!m.find(0)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not unwrap this code. Most probably it was not wrapped with the Oracle 10g, 11g or 12c wrap utility.");
    } else {
      int encodedCodeLength = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2).trim(), 16);
      int expectedLength = m.end() + encodedCodeLength;
      if (expectedLength > wrappedUnix.length()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrapped code seems to be truncated. Expected length of " + expectedLength + " characters but got only " + wrappedUnix.length() + ".");
      } else {
        String encoded = wrappedUnix.substring(m.end(), expectedLength);
        byte[] decoded = Base64Coder.decodeLines(encoded);
        byte[] remapped = new byte[decoded.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < decoded.length; ++i) {
          int unsignedInteger = decoded[i] & 255;
          remapped[i] = (byte)charmap[unsignedInteger];
        }

        byte[] hash = Arrays.copyOfRange(remapped, 0, 20);
        byte[] zipped = Arrays.copyOfRange(remapped, 20, remapped.length);
        byte[] calculatedHash = HashCalculator.getSHA1(zipped);
        if (!Arrays.equals(hash, calculatedHash)) {
          throw new RuntimeException("SHA-1 hash values do not match. Expected '" + HashCalculator.bytesToHex(hash) + "' but got '" + HashCalculator.bytesToHex(calculatedHash) + "'. Cannot unwrap code.");
        } else {
          byte[] unzipped = Unzipper.unzip(zipped);

          int size;
          for(size = unzipped.length; size > 0 && unzipped[size - 1] == 0; --size) {
          }

          return new String(unzipped, 0, size);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```